# Problema com uma lista de stopwords no weka

Tags: weka

Olá, estou com um problema que é o seguinte:

Estou tentando aplicar uma lista de stopword personalizada a um filtro do Weka e esta me dando o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem do erro]

A lista é um arquivo txt que peguei desse site: https://gist.github.com/alopes/5358189

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está declarando o arquivo txt. No campo stopwords, que está Weka-3-8, você deve colocar o caminho da pasta ou diretório onde está seu arquivo txt.